# Make a rectangle knowing the position of the two vertical lines of the sides (path elements)

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to make a rectangle knowing the position of the two vertical lines of the sides. The lines are implemented as follows:

```
<path fill="#000000" id="Measure1" d="M159.688,119.75L159.688,88.75L160.28799999999998,88.75L160.28799999999998,119.75ZM162.688,119.75L162.688,88.75L163.28799999999998,88.75L163.28799999999998,119.75Z"/>

<path fill="#000000" id="Measure2" d="M260.168,119.75L260.168,88.75L260.76800000000003,88.75L260.76800000000003,119.75Z"/>
```

With this code I have a rectangle:

```
<path d="M10 80 H 110 V 130 H   10 V  80 Z" fill="red" />
```

But can I use the coordinates of the two lines to use them to give my rectangle the position?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the bounding box of the lines with SVG's native `getBBox()`, and then calculate the positions, here is a basic example:

```
var path1 = document.getElementById("Measure1");
var path2 = document.getElementById("Measure2");
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");

var bbox1 = path1.getBBox();
var bbox2 = path2.getBBox();

var x = bbox1.x + bbox1.width;
var y =  bbox1.y;
var width = bbox2.x - x;
var height =  bbox1.height;

var rect = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "rect");
rect.setAttribute("x", x);
rect.setAttribute("y", y);
rect.setAttribute("width", width);
rect.setAttribute("height", height);
rect.setAttribute("fill", "red");
svg.appendChild(rect);
```

You can see the result here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3rSYV/